# PHP Laravel check if two arrays has a matching key value and if so take a element from array 1 and insert in array 2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a few arrays that look like this:

```
['itemId' => 2, 'title' => 'someTitle', 'bulk_id' => 4]
['itemId' => 3, 'title' => 'someTitle', 'bulk_id' => 5]
['itemId' => 4, 'title' => 'someTitle', 'bulk_id' => 6]
```

And three more that looks like this:

```
['info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 6]
['info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 5]
['info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 4]
```

Now I want to find the arrays that has a matching `bulk_id` and when I do I want to take the **itemId** element of the first array and add the second array so it would become this:

```
['itemId' => 4, 'info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 6]
['itemId' => 3, 'info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 5]
['itemId' => 2, 'info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 4]
```

Does PhP or Laravel have any helper function for checking and combining arrays?

Comment: It looks like the data comes from DB, so use Eloquent relationships instead of reinventing the wheel by trying to combine the arrays.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Only one of the arrays are comming from DB, the other one is a user input. I need to combine the two arrays like I described above in order to do a bulk insert with the second arrays

Comment: you can use the array map function for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eloquent collection `map()` to merge and `toArray()` to make it array again.

```
$merged = collect($arrays2)->map(function ($value) use ($arrays1)  {

        foreach($arrays1 as $array){
            if($value["bulk_id"]==$array["bulk_id"]){
                $value["itemId"] = $array["itemId"];
            }
        }

        return $value;
    });

    return $merged->toArray();
```

Comment: I only want to take ``itemId`` and its value from array1 and insert it into array 2 if they have  a matching bulk id. Not merge all elements from both arrays all together

Comment: @Kiow run this code, you will have what you are looking for. I didn't merge anything here, its just the name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$first_arrays = [
  ['itemId' => 2, 'title' => 'someTitle', 'bulk_id' => 4],
  ['itemId' => 3, 'title' => 'someTitle', 'bulk_id' => 5],
  ['itemId' => 4, 'title' => 'someTitle', 'bulk_id' => 6],
];

$second_arrays = [
  ['info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 6],
  ['info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 5],
  ['info' => 'someInfo', 'bulk_id' => 4],
];

function sort_by_bulk(array $a, array $b) : int {
    return $a['bulk_id'] <=> $b['bulk_id'];
}

usort($first_arrays, 'sort_by_bulk');
usort($second_arrays, 'sort_by_bulk');

$combined = array_map('array_merge', $first_arrays, $second_arrays);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZEAG6

If you need to clean up stragglers (items that have no corresponding bulk id), you could use `array_filter` to clean out anything that doesn't have an info key